# Infragistics contentPane(Silverlight) should not move/dragged

Tags: silverlight, infragistics

While using Infragistics content pane I need a facility that user should not be able to either dock or move the control. I have tried AllowDocking false which works for docking & for non moving I have tried IsFloating=False & AllowDockingFloating=false.

```
<ig:ContentPane x:Name="WorkspacesPane" IsFloating="False" AllowDockingFloating="False"   IsMaximized="False" AllowDocking="False" Header="Workspaces" Location="Left" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" MinWidth="250" IsActivePane="True" CloseButtonVisibility="Collapsed" WindowPositionMenuVisibility="Collapsed">
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to enable and disable?

```
WorkspacesPane.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

Comment: I don't want to enable or disable, I don't want to let user drag/float the dock window.

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan. That disables the control altogether I have tree control inside it where user chooses an item. What I want is user should not be able to move it, not to disable the control.

Comment: To be more precise I am working on security, where user may or may not have access to move the dockable control around the screen based on given permission.

Comment: got the solution here : http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/86863/433458.aspx#433458

Answer (score 0):

IsHitTestVisible helped but it was disabling the control. so through infragistic got few styles to be applied to disable the drag feature but still keep control enabled.

The sample is here :http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/86863/433458.aspx#433458